# Adapt generic Action<T> delegates to non-generic Action delegate

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a question on how to properly adapt generic `Action<T>` delegates to simple non-generic version of `Action` delegate. The non-generic `Action` delegate instance will be used as constructor parameter in `Task` class. 
The root function to call is `TaskUtils.ExecuteAction(Action action, bool isAsync = true)`

I have a piece of code. I wish you could point to my errors or advise some other way to implement. I do have a doubt over capturing context of method arguments

```
public static class TaskUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes ACTION delegate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    /// <param name="isAsync"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Task ExecuteAction(Action action, bool isAsync = true)
    {
        // validate action delegate
        Action execAction = Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(action, nameof(action), "Action delegate is not set (NULL)");

        if (!isAsync)
        {
            // do action execute
            try
            {
                execAction();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // failed handler
                return Task.FromException(ex);
            }
        }

        // run a task in the system thread-pool
        return Task.Run(action, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Adapter function to fit ACTION delegte
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    /// <param name="arg"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Action AdaptToRootAction<T>(Action<T> action, T arg)
    {
        // copy param
        T param = arg;

        return delegate
        {
            // pass parameter 
            // and invoke ACTION
            action(param);
        };
    }

    public static Action AdaptToRootAction<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
    {
        T1 param1 = arg1;
        T2 param2 = arg2;

        return delegate
        {
            // pass two generic parameters
            // and invoke ACTION delegate
            action(param1, param2);
        };
    }

    public static Action AdaptToRootAction<T1, T2, T3>(Action<T1, T2, T3> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
    {
        T1 param1 = arg1;
        T2 param2 = arg2;
        T3 param3 = arg3;

        return delegate
        {
            // pass three generic parameters
            // and invoke ACTION delegate
            action(param1, param2, param3);
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a generic <see cref="Action{T}"/> with a passed value of type <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    /// <param name="arg"></param>
    /// <param name="isAsync"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Task ExecuteAction<T>(Action<T> action, T arg, bool isAsync = true)
    {
        // adapt to root Action delegate and invoke 
        Action rootAction = AdaptToRootAction<T>(action, arg);
        return ExecuteAction(rootAction, isAsync);
    }


    public static Task ExecuteAction<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, bool isAsync = true)
    {
        // adapt to root Action delegate and invoke
        Action rootAction = AdaptToRootAction<T1, T2>(action, arg1, arg2);
        return ExecuteAction(rootAction, isAsync);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does simple lambda `() => genericAction(arg)` not work?

Comment: Not yet, but I think that lamdas are used here implicitly

Comment: @NickReshetinsky Out of curiosity, may i ask what you are solving using this class?

Comment: What is your _specific question_? Please explain precisely what the code you have now does, and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: Ok, my question is - if I make a non-generic Action delegate from the generic one, will method params get captured properly, I mean T1, T2, T3?

Comment: @NickReshetinsky - Isn't the thing you're trying to do just this: `public static Action AdaptToRootAction<T>(Action<T> action, T arg) { return () => action(arg); }`?

Comment: Yes, it is, but I wonder if it's necessary to copy parameter [arg] to a new local variable and pass it to the action delegate or it's not necessary??
I mean

Comment: What you've done by declaring a local param is not necessary, just pass the argument right away into the inner Action. You can try that and test that yourself, it's easy.